# How to get query time and space information from BigQuery API

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm going to build a web app and use BigQuery as a part of backend database, and I want to show the query cost information (ex. 1.8 sec elapsed, 264.9 MB processed) in the app.

I know we can check the BigQuery's query information inside GCP, but how do we I get that information from BigQuery API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are interested in is present in the job statistics.

See jobs.get for more details: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get

The dry-run sample may be of interest as well, though you can get the stats from a real invocation as well (dry run is for estimating costs without executing the query):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-dry-run

Comment: Thanks for the dry run sample code, I'm wondering if there is a sample code for query storage and query costs of an actual job.

Comment: Simply don't set the dry run property.

Comment: I see. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from math import floor, log


def format_bytes(size):
    power = 0 if size <= 0 else floor(log(size, 1024))
    return f"{round(size / 1024 ** power, 2)} {['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'][int(power)]}"

def run_bigquery(query=''):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(dry_run=True, use_query_cache=False)
    if not query:
        return []
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
    bytes_scanned = format_bytes(query_job.total_bytes_processed)

    if 'GB' in bytes_scanned or 'TB' in bytes_scanned:
        print(query)
        print(f'Alert: Query data scan costs might be higher: {bytes_scanned}')
        return []
    
    df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()
    df['bytes_scanned'] = bytes_scanned
    return df.to_dict('records')
```

This is the simple logic, I generally use in my code prevent the surprise bigquery cost!

This doesn't answer exactly your question though.